# Expression.Body removes class on static method call

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I have an Expression with a certain Lambda in it that looks like this:

```
Expression<Func<string[],int>> expression = p => int.Parse(p[0]) * int.Parse(p[1])
```

when I call expression.Body, I get:

```
(Parse(p[0]) * Parse(p[1]))
```

if the expression would be like this:

```
Expression<Func<string[],int>> expression = p => p[0].ToInt() * p[1]ToInt()
```

naturally, the expression cuts off the class from a static method and do with it something.

My question is, how can i get a string representation with the excluded class?
where does it store the static method? can i `string.Format()` the properties to get the full body?

p.s. I don't need to run the expression, i know that it will work when I'll call `expression.Invoke`. since I'm using CodeDom, I need the exact expression body

Comment: Have you looked at the actual contents of the expression tree? I suspect this is only an issue with the `ToString` result - how much do you care about that? What are you doing with it?

Comment: Please provide an example of the output you want.

Comment: @Lucas , the output i would like is `int.Parse(p[0]) * int.Parse(p[1])`
just to add the class name before the static method name.

Comment: hi @JonSkeet , as i wrote, this expression is being pasted to a CodeDom compiler and being executed. I can't tell if it's a `ToString` issue since i see that result on the intelisense but maybe it is also using `ToString` to show the value

Comment: Where did you write that? The words "compiler", "pasted" and "executed" didn't appear until that comment. Read your question: it doesn't explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: sorry @JonSkeet , i just thought that it is irrelevant to the question. I mentioned CodeDom in the "p.s." to say that i don't need to invoke the expression. I just need the `expression.Body` string

Comment: You mentioned that you're using CodeDom, but that's *all* you said about it - and that covers a very broad range of uses. Please edit your question with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Expression.ToString()` will instantiate an `ExpressionStringBuilder`, which unfortunately is `internal sealed` so you can't  do much about it.

[See the relevant source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Ast/ExpressionStringBuilder.cs).

You can try the following workaround:

- Create a subclass of `ExpressionVisitor`
- Instantiate a `StringBuilder` in the constructor
- Override `VisitMethodCall` to implement your logic and append the string to the `StringBuilder`. Use `MethodInfo.DeclaringType` to access the method's type.
- For the other node types, just append `node.ToString()` to the `StringBuilder` (reuse the existing functionality).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just by looking inside i've learnt a lot but unfortunatelly, it doesn't help me because this brings me back to square one. you see, inside VisitMethodCall, I still don't have the full name of the static method and by that i mean: when I call `Phone.Parse`, the class `Phone` is not in the node properties. I will get a method info with the name of the method `Parse` but the type will be of the return type.

Comment: @armageddon Look at `DeclaringType` of the `MethodInfo`.

Comment: thanks @svick , found it. I think it should be added to the answer